# XCode5 Link Testflight SDK library

Tags: linker, xcode5, static-libraries, testflight

i want to use libTestFlight.a library in my project, i already import it in "Link Binaries With Libraries", also in build phases, i tried to add "**Search Path**" and "**Header Path**", i also tried to change the **ARCH** to **Standard architectures (armv7, armv7s)**, but still no luck, it always give this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_deflate", referenced from:
      __tf_remote_log_compress_data in libTestFlight.a(tf_remote_log_io.o)
  "_deflateInit_", referenced from:
      __tf_remote_log_compress_data in libTestFlight.a(tf_remote_log_io.o)
  "_deflateEnd", referenced from:
      __tf_remote_log_compress_data in libTestFlight.a(tf_remote_log_io.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Add the libz.dylib as the Link Binary With Libraries.

Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries > push the + button > search the libz.dylib and select it > push the Add button.